# How do I print a short as an unsigned short in Java

Tags: java, unsigned, short, ushort

I have an array of short whose values range between 0 and the maximum value of a short.  I scale the data (to display it as TYPE_USHORT) so that the resulting short values range between 0 and 65535.  I need to print some of the scaled values but can't figure out how.  The data are in an array and in a BufferedImage.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The simplest way is to convert to int:

```
short s = ...;
int i = s & 0xffff;
```

The bitmask is to make the conversion give a value in the range 0-65535 rather than -32768-32767.

Comment: Quite effective, but less readable than `Short.toUnsignedInt()`.

Comment: @scottb: True - that only became available about four years after the answer was written though :)

Answer (score 23):

Since Java 1.8, the same can be done with `Short.toUnsignedInt`:

```
System.out.println("signed s=" + s + ", unsigned s=" + Short.toUnsignedInt(s))
```

Comment: What a difference time makes.